# How to build JSON array before posting to other document?

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am reading one document requests processed trough another document using AJAX.

In document processed trough AJAX i want to generate JSON array because its only way i can pass two variables and then spread them like this

```
$('#country').append($('<option>').text(arr_values[1]).attr('value', arr_values[0])));
```

now i generating code like this

```
  $results2 = mysql_query('SELECT full, short FROM `Countries` WHERE '.$cities);
   $json = array();
   while( $result2 = mysql_fetch_array($results2) ) {
        $json[] = $result2['short'].','.$result2['full'];
   }
```

Comment: How can i build json ARRAY i assume there are two ways to transfer info one in string as i do it but then i cannot break this string using above function it takes both values. If i transfer as array perhaps then i can address each value individually? What i need is to create option with different value and name

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode` manual is pretty clear about its usage, check 'Example #2 A json_encode() example showing all the options in action' in http://ar.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

`json_encode` converts standard php arrays to JSON.

Anyway, your SQL code is not correct. You must use `mysql_fetch_array` for getting the values from `results2`, and 'short' and 'full' are not in your query.

Comment: I paste old code this is how it looks actually, fixed original post.